# Unable to get the timed value from log line or scripted fields on Kibana/Elasticsearch

Tags: angular, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am using ELK version 6.1.1 with in my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. The client side of this is for gathering analytics by graph and is already present in angular 4 framework. All the analytical graph visualization are coming from embedded Iframes which changes dynamically whenever duration is changed. I am sending the time duration string inside the iframe graphs urls to get the updated graphs according the duration.

Problem Statement:-
I am having some scripted fields which perfom some calculations of the fields got from log line. Now, while creating visualizations according to a duration say 6 months from now, I would need the value of the scripted field which belongs to the start time of the selected duration i.e. of date-time which is 6 months from now. Further using this scripted value (of a particular time) and sum of other scripted fields the visulaization would get complete. Thus the visualization should get updated according to the selected duration i.e. on day, 1 week, 1 month, 6 month etc.

Can anyone please suggest any way of getting the scripted field value which belongs to a specific time and use it in my Kibana visualizations?

Thanks.